# How can I deploy my node js app (a realtime tracking) to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

Ive tried to deploy a node js app to heroku. but an application error always occur..

**here's my web logs**

> 2018-02-19T09:00:51.759639+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2018-02-19T09:00:54.029447+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `node index.js`
>   2018-02-19T09:00:55.992998+00:00 app[web.1]: server started on port
>   3000 2018-02-19T09:01:54.487612+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot
>   timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of
>   launch 2018-02-19T09:01:54.487612+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping
>   process with SIGKILL 2018-02-19T09:01:54.622011+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   State changed from starting to crashed
>   2018-02-19T09:01:54.608384+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 137

and in my terminal it warns that there's no env file found

here's the updated logs..

> 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164758+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile
>   (module.js:570:32) 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164760+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>   2018-02-20T22:33:28.164761+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load
>   (module.js:487:32) 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164763+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12) 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164765+00:00
>   app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>   2018-02-20T22:33:28.164766+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain
>   (module.js:604:10) 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164768+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7) 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164769+00:00
>   app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
>   2018-02-20T22:33:28.164771+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   bootstrap_node.js:504:3 2018-02-20T22:33:41.623294+00:00
>   heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
>   path="/" host=realtime-tracker.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=f5ccc5ea-8044-454e-95d5-9175b93a4be3 fwd="110.54.168.160"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2018-02-20T22:33:42.405421+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=realtime-tracker.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=9a88d409-6292-4361-b6ca-057e8b8fd5ad fwd="110.54.168.160"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https Disconnected
>   from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see
>   here! Attempting to reconnect... 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164758+00:00
>   app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>   2018-02-20T22:33:28.164760+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>   2018-02-20T22:33:28.164761+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load
>   (module.js:487:32) 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164763+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12) 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164765+00:00
>   app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>   2018-02-20T22:33:28.164766+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain
>   (module.js:604:10) 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164768+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7) 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164769+00:00
>   app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
>   2018-02-20T22:33:28.164771+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   bootstrap_node.js:504:3 2018-02-20T22:33:41.623294+00:00
>   heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
>   path="/" host=realtime-tracker.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=f5ccc5ea-8044-454e-95d5-9175b93a4be3 fwd="110.54.168.160"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2018-02-20T22:33:42.405421+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=realtime-tracker.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=9a88d409-6292-4361-b6ca-057e8b8fd5ad fwd="110.54.168.160"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https Disconnected
>   from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see
>   here! Attempting to reconnect... 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164758+00:00
>   app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>   2018-02-20T22:33:28.164760+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>   2018-02-20T22:33:28.164761+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load
>   (module.js:487:32) 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164763+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12) 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164765+00:00
>   app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>   2018-02-20T22:33:28.164766+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain
>   (module.js:604:10) 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164768+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7) 2018-02-20T22:33:28.164769+00:00
>   app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
>   2018-02-20T22:33:28.164771+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   bootstrap_node.js:504:3 2018-02-20T22:33:41.623294+00:00
>   heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
>   path="/" host=realtime-tracker.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=f5ccc5ea-8044-454e-95d5-9175b93a4be3 fwd="110.54.168.160"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2018-02-20T22:33:42.405421+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=realtime-tracker.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=9a88d409-6292-4361-b6ca-057e8b8fd5ad fwd="110.54.168.160"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku dynamically assigns you a port as an environment variable (`PORT`). Don't try to force a listen on a specific port, instead use:

```
listen(process.env.PORT)
```

Comment: sorry for the late response.. What should be the content of my .env file?

Comment: @RenanNuevo I found a GitHub issue where the following code solved their probem - declare your port like this. `var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;`

Comment: it workded! thank you Evyatar Meged. It's really a big help! Gob bless